# How can I get certain text from wikipedia?

Tags: java, android

Take this for example:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_Bill_of_Rights

Under the "Amendments" section, I want to get what each bullet point says, and display them in a nice list in an android application. I know there's a wikimedia api, but I have absolutely no idea how to use it, and from what I understand of it, you can get the text under a section, but I'm not sure if you can get each bullet point separately.

What would be the best way to do this? Or instead of this, should I just spend my time copying the text from over 300 pages onto a text file, and reading it in the application?

Comment: Just copying the bullet points seems like a valid strategy. But where are these 300 pages you speak of? You have only linked to one. Are you referring to the translations of the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This link uses the mediawiki API to query the page from you question ([based on this wiki article](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Query#Sample_query)):

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&format=xml&titles=United_States_Bill_of_Rights
```

As you can see, it returns an xml document, the page text is found under the `<rev>` tag. And it is the plain editor text in mediawiki text markup language.

So to extract the information from this text you should use a parse. [Here is a list of alternative parsers](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Alternative_parsers), some are written in Java.

Answer (score 1):

I am sure you would have already thought of this:

- If your goal is to view Wiki in your app, you can use WebView
- If your goal is to capture specific data elements you can download the html page and string process it (div >> ol/ul >> li)